# How to get current timestamp of playhead during live stream playback on Chromecast

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, chromecast, live-streaming, shaka

When playing a live stream on Chromecast I would like to know the absolute time (timestamp) of the current playhead, as this would be useful to me when the user pauses playback.

Is there any way to access this info via CAF or maybe to access the shaka player and acquire the info via its functions?

I've tried to use the following CAF featured mentioned in the documentation:

```
this.playerDataBinder = new cast.framework.ui.PlayerDataBinder(this.playerData);
```

Which updated the `playerData` object to contain various pieces of info about the playback, but none of them seem to be relevant in my case.

I would need to know the exact timestamp in a pause event so that later on, even after swithing streams (which is a requirement in some cases) I would be able to identify this absolute timestamp in the new stream as well and seek to that moment when resuming.